# Table Calculation in python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am still early on in my python journey and I have encountered a problem. I have a fairly large table similar to the one shown below;

| Haz | Fault - floats | Mit - floats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H1 | F1 | M1 |
| H1 | F1 | M2 |
| H1 | F1 | M3 |
| H1 | F1 | M4 |
| H1 | F2 | M5 |
| H1 | F3 | M6 |
| H1 | F3 | M7 |
| H1 | F3 | M8 |
| H2 | F4 | M8 |
| H2 | F4 | M9 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| H20 | F87 | M435 |

For each unique "Fault", I need to obtain a probability value (FM) through the following equation;

```
FM = [(1-M1)*(1-M2)...*(1-Mn)] * Fn
```

And then, for each unique "Haz", I need to obtain a probability value (HM) through the following equation;

```
HM = 1-[(1-FM1)*(1-FM2)...*(1-FMn)]
```

Any guidance on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: What is `Fn` in your `FM` formula?

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks for responding. Fn represents a fault value. For example to calculate a fault probability value for F1; FM1 = [(1-M1)*(1-M2)*(1-M3)*(1-M4)] * F1. Another example to calculate a fault probability value for F2; FM2 = [(1-M5)*F2

Comment: But what type of values are they? Some actual sample data would make the problem easier to understand

Comment: Mit and Fault are floats, updated the description above as well

Comment: And `Haz` is a string?

Comment: Haz is a string correct H1, H2, H3 .... H20

Comment: Why are faults described by a floating point number?

Comment: Fn is a float with a value of <= 1 but > 0. The float represents a probability of a fault occurring. However, the true probability of any given fault occuring is derived through the equation for FM as it incorporates mitigation effectiveness (Mit). Mit is also a float with a value of <= 1 but > 0.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but if you describe faults by a floating point number, what happens if two faults have the same probability?

Comment: That's possible. Two or more faults (e.g. F1 and F2) can have the same probability. Same with Mit. Two or more Mits (e.g. M1 and M2) can have the same probability. What makes it unique is the Fault - Mit combination i.e. FM

Comment: But if two faults have the same probability, how can you know which `M` values belong to which fault?

Comment: i was thinking something along the lines of assigning each F and M value a variable?

Comment: Alternatively just give the faults a name (as you have with the hazards). That way the grouping is well defined. I don't think the M values need a name though, as they will only occur on lines with the relevant fault

Comment: yeah fair good point Nick, would you be kind enough to show me an example line of code to get me started? I am not quite sure how i can go about iterating through each row and assign them a variable?